# Issues with creating default broadcast (POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts)

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to create default broadcast for my live stream with privacy set to 'unlisted' or 'private' bud it's always being created with privacy 'public', event though privacyStatus field is provided in request body:

REQUEST:

```js
 const res = await this.request(callback => youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert({
      auth: auth,
      part: 'snippet,contentDetails,status',
      resource: {
          snippet: {
              title: "Some Title",
              description: "Some description",
              scheduledStartTime: "2020-03-11T12:08:43.087Z,
              isDefaultBroadcast: true
          },
          status: {
              privacyStatus: 'unlisted'
          },
      }
 }, callback))
```

CHUNK OF RESPONSE:

```
data: 
...
     status: 
      { lifeCycleStatus: 'ready',
        privacyStatus: 'public',
        recordingStatus: 'notRecording',
        selfDeclaredMadeForKids: false }},
...
```

Is this a normal behaviour, or am i doing something wrong ? BTW `update` works fine.

If this is a normal behaviour it should be mentioned somewhere here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert